# В чем разница между DISTINCT и GROUP BY?

Tags: sql

Читаем:

> Оператор **SQL DISTINCT** используется для указания на то, что следует
>   работать только с уникальными значениями столбца.
>
> Оператор **SQL GROUP BY** используется для объединения результатов
>   выборки по одному или нескольким столбцам.

В результате работы с этими предикатами мы получаем уникальные записи по какому либо ключу. Не могу понять в чем их различие.

---- Добалено -----

В моем понимании что GROUP BY - это группировка по какому либо признаку, а то есть например есть поле со значениями:

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

после **GROUP BY** они должны стать:

```
1
1
2
2
3
3
```

а на деле получаем:

```
1
2
3
```

В чем причина?

Comment: в случае с `group by` мы получаем на выходе *дерево*

Comment: @Bald, а как происходит вывод из дерева если это не табличная структура?

Comment: а вот этот вопрос уже к Вам, для полученного дерева можно получить какое то значение применив `Sum(),Min(),Max(),...` или же вы сами сможете его построить... обходя результаты группировки

Comment: @Bald, вот теперь стало понятно, мы можем получить вычисляемую запись. я прав?

Comment: если говорить про ваш пример то при помощи `group by` можно получить например количество дубликатов, или например сумму заказа состоящего из некоторого кол-ва позиций сделав группировку по *заказу*

Comment: @Bald, ну смотрите как работает мое видиние ) : получить - это значит взять, вычислить - это значит применить какое либо действие. если без придирок то мне теперь все ясно. большое спасибо за то что откликнулись. ваше слово **дерево** внесло ясность в суть моей проблемы.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46330/discussion-between-bald-and-perfect).

Comment: Странный вообще вопрос! Это почти что спросить чем машина отличается от велосипедного колеса, несвязные вещи по сути

Answer (score 18, accepted):

DISTINCT - получить уникальные строки (отличающиеся друг от друга любым отображаемым полем). Работает чуть быстрее.

GROUP BY - сгруппировать по какому-либо признаку, при этом можно использовать агрегатные функции SUM, AVG, MAX и т.д.

### Добавлено

Дано

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

С помощью ORDER BY получим сортировку

```
1
1
2
2
3
3
```

С помощью DISTINCT уникальные значения

```
1
2
3
```

А с помощью GROUP BY можно посчитать кол-во вхождений

```
SELECT value, COUNT(*) FROM table_test
value COUNT(*)
1      2
2      2
3      2
```

Comment: скажем есть поле с набором записей {1,1,2,2,3,3} . можно применить к нему DISTINCT и получить {1,2,3} а можно применить GROUP BY и получить {1,2,3}. и первое и второе одно и то же. так в чем разница? Определение я прочитать вполне способен а вот в чем разница их работы мне не совсем понятна..

Comment: @perfect вы не совсем правильный пример приводите..... выполняют они разную функцию.... например вам нужно в столбце name выбрать только уникальные имена, тогда поможет Distinct.......... А если вам нужно например посчитать сумму рублей за все приобретенные товары на каждого покупателя - там будет Group ..даже если миллион юзеров с одинаковыми именами там будет........ никаким образом distinct не поможет..

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, а как все приобретенные товары этим человеком попадут в одну единственную запись и вычислятся? Может я не совсем понимаю что в SELECT приходит.. Для меня SELECT это некий фильтр по колонкам(полям)

Comment: А за счет чего distinct работает чуть быстрее ? фактически он выполняет ту же сортировку, для подавления одинаковых строк ...

Comment: @perfect А вы поэкспериментируйте, так быстрее поймете. А select это не фильтр.  Условие where в нем это фильтр. А group by - это правила _объединения нескольких записей в одну_

Comment: @Mike хороший вопрос: может Вы сами на него ответите/прокоментируете?!

Comment: @Mark Может добавите примерно такую формулировку: для distinct _"(удаляет дубли)"_, для group by _"Объединяет несколько строк в одну, с возможностью использовать агрегатные функции"_

Answer (score 6):

Разница в механике работы. Distinct - возвращает уникальные значения, GroupBy - группирует ВСЕ значения. В некоторых случаях результат будет одним и тем же. Правило использование простое - если можно использовать Distinct, используй его, если нет - то Gorup by.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT исключает из результата повторяющиеся строки. SELECT DISTINCT ON исключает строки, совпадающие по всем указанным выражениям. SELECT ALL (по умолчанию) возвращает все строки результата, включая дубликаты.

GROUP BY - просто схлопывает повторяющиеся результаты в один.